# Data attribute on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript

I am creating elements dynamically, this is the code i use for one cell.

I want to add a data attribute with a custom value.

I have tried:

```
elCostPrice.data-num = i;

elCostPrice.data["num"] = i;

elCostPrice.prop["num", i]
```

but none of those worked

```
var Cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
var elCostPrice = document.createElement('input');
elCostPrice.type = 'text';
elCostPrice.className = 'cost_price form-control required';
elCostPrice.name = 'cost_price' + i;
elCostPrice.id = 'cost_price' + i;
elCostPrice.placeholder = 'Cost Price';
elCostPrice.value = cost_price;
Cell3.appendChild(elCostPrice);
```

Comment: You're not using any jQuery logic at all in the question. Did you mean to tag it `javascript` instead? Also note, the issue is because you need to use `dataset`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: i did, my mistake thank you

Comment: I agree with Rory, and if you want to set custom attributes in JS then use setAttribute() function instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use  [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

> The `HTMLElement.dataset` property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element, either in HTML or in the DOM.

```
elCostPrice.dataset.num = i;
```

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways:

1. Use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):  `elCostPrice.setAttribute("data-num", i);`
2. Use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset): `elCostPrice.dataset.num = i;`